# TableView in View, how do i make it transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table-view embedded in to a main view, its the only way i can use static tables. The main view has a fixed background color, which the embeded view does not inhreit, and it is not transparent, is there any way to do this?

It seems stupid to declare the color twice for one view

Comment: just set the Background color of the UITablView to "Clear Color"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.35];
```

Comment: Your tableViewCells may also need to have their `opaque` property set to `NO` and/or their `backgrounColor` set to `[UIColor clearColor]`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to setting the table view's background color to `[UIColor clearColor]`, you may also need to implement this delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

I've had to do this in the past because cells set their background color after returning from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks its very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `setAlpha` property to specify a float value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 based on what transparency you need, for instance:

```
[self.tableView setAlpha:0.5];
```

Answer (score 1):

for swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

}
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    cell.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can set the background colour to clear colour and alpha to one

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.7.2

```swift
//Set table view background to clear in UI or with code below
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```