# How to set alpha and content mode on UITableView background image programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview which has a background image. I had set it programatically but don't know how to set alpha and content mode.
Here is my code what I had done:-

```
tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Launch-Image_Sample5"))
```

If anyone knows about this. Thank you!

Comment: `alpha and content mode` for what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
 let tempImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Launch-Image_Sample5"))
 tempImageView.frame = self.tableView.frame 
 tempImageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill 
 tempImageView.clipsToBounds = false
 self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

and set the alpha as

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: postTableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

 cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5) // or use   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
}
```

for more reference see [this](https://grokswift.com/transparent-table-view/)

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766152/tableview-in-view-how-do-i-make-it-transparent